# Confusion over system libariries that ship with mono

Tags: mono

I've installed mono 2.10 along with monodevelop and have used monodelveop to code some apps under ubuntu. Several of these apps needed to access to the JavaScriptSerializer, which is part of the System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace.

In order to be able to instantiate and use a JavaScriptSerializer, I had to add a reference to my app in monodevelop - but I see there appear to be two packages that I can chose from: one named "system.web.extensions" and the other named "mono".

If I use the first package (system.web.extensions) I get a runtime error when using the JavaSerializer. I tried using the "mono" reference instead and it works fine.

So far so good. But now, I want to run this same app under windows and I'm getting a "cannot load assembly" error for System.Web.Exceptions.

I'm confused at this point:  Why are there two packages shipped with mono/monodevelop for some of these assemblies, and which one(s) should I be using in order to be cross-platform?

Thanks!
Michael

Answer (score 2):

> Why are there two packages shipped with mono/monodevelop for some of
>   these assemblies?

Mono assemblies are kinds of internal assemblies: they provide additional features, not included in the .NET Framework. The System assemblies rely sometimes on these (i.e. Mono.Web for ASP.NET Web services).

> Which one(s) should I be using in order to be cross-platform?

Always use the System ones. The Mono assemblies are not available under .NET Framework (unless you ship them manually).

Mono 2.10 provides two versions of the System.Web.Extensions assembly: 1.0.61025.0 and 4.0.0.0. Be sure to use the 4.0 version.
If the problem persists, could you post your code? (for me, no problem using the JavaScriptSerializer)